# Why this class may not be publish safely?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

```
public class Holder {
　　　　private int n;
　　　　public Holder(int n) {
    　　　　this.n = n;
　　　　}
　　　　public void assertSanity() {
    　　　　if(n != n) {
        　　　　throw new AssertionError("something is wrong!");
    　　　　}
　　　　}
}
```

This code snippet is from JCIP Listing 3.15. On the foot note it said:

> While it may seem that field values set in a constructor are the first values written to those fields and therefore that there are no "older"
>  values to see as stale values, the Object constructor first writes the default values to all fields before subclass constructors run. It is therefore
>  possible to see the default value for a field as a stale value.

I am confused if the class has only these variable and method, how could it be not thread safe, even with subclass instantiated? Because the method call to `assertSanity` will be blocked by the constructor method, so I think it will always be set correctly when you call that method.

It will be great help if you can build a possible sub-class leading to a race condition here.